# User ID is NULL when saving record for logged in user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, session, activerecord

I am starting to learn rails and have run into a problem. I am writing a simple application (similar to the twitter tutorials I have seen) where a user logs in and creates a new post.

When a user logs in, I am setting the session information as follows

```
    session[:id] = authorized_user.id
    session[:email] = authorized_user.email
```

So now I have the ID of the user logged in. Upon login, the user is brought to a form where they can submit a new post (3 fields.) When user clicks submit, I want to create a new record with the data they entered, and associate the record to that user (User ID). I am not exactly sure how to do this.

Below is the code on the controller:

```
def create
#Used for creating new status posts
#Need to get the ID of the user logged in
@user = AdminUser.find(session[:id])
#Instantiate new object using form parameters
@post = Post.new(post_params) 
@post.AdminUser = @user  # THIS IS THE LINE NOT WORKING
#Save the object
if @post.save
  #If save succeeds, redirect to the index action
  flash[:notice] = "Status has been saved"
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
else
  #If the save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
  render('new')
end
end
```

Here is the Private method for post_params

```
def post_params
#Defining the params that are allowed to be passed with forms.
params.require(:post).permit(:post_status, :post_title, :post_content)
end
```

The record is saved but the UserID for the record is NULL.

My first instict was to try to pass UserID as a post parameter, but i think this is a potential security risk, so I am trying to figure out an alternate way. I am sure it is something simple and I am just missing it.

Comment: Do you have `user_id` attribute in your `Post` Model?

Comment: post models admin_user and post

Comment: Also post the `log` generated while `submitting` the `form`.

Comment: Also, where is `authorized_user` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the line like this, taking `UserID` as the column name in `posts` table

```
@post.UserID = @user.id
```

Answer (score 1):

**Attributes**

Firstly,

```
@post.AdminUser = @user  # THIS IS THE LINE NOT WORKING
```

You should use [snake_case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for your attribute names (you're using [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)). Calling an attribute AdminUser has all sorts of potential issues which will arise down the line.

Call it `admin_user` or `admin_id` or something similar

--

**Params**

Secondly,

> I want to create a new record with the data they entered, and
>   associate the record to that user (User ID)

If you're trying to save a "dependent" record for an object (for example, saving a `post` for a `user`), you'll have to assign the `user_id` record yourself, and pass it through the params, like so:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def create
         @post = Post.new(post_params)
         @post.save
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body).merge({user_id: authorized_user.id})
    end
end
```

When you create an element in your app, you're basically just taking data from the params hash & sending to the model to save. This is done using the `strong_params` functionality introduced in Rails 4:

```
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body).merge({user_id: authorized_user.id})
    end
```

As you can see from my example above, you basically need to be able to send through the `user_id` / `admin_id` / `AdminUser` value through to the model (so it can save)

You can also do this by setting the attribute as the example below:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
   @post.user_id = authorized_user.id
   @post.save
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
end
```

--

You should also look at the [difference between authentication & autorhization](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/authentication-vs-authorization/) for better definition of your logged-in user object :)

Comment: Thanks Pavan - it's definitely the most apt for the question I think

Comment: Yes!.It is.And the OP shouldn't be using `CamelCase` like `UserID`.

Comment: @rich-peck - Thank you very much for the information. Shortly after posting I did alter the line to read:

`@post.admin_user_id = @user` 

It did not work. As RSB suggested, I needed to add .id to the line.

Anyways, I attempted to change the case like you mentioned but then I get undefined variable/method error. AdminUsers is the table name, so is it still incorrect to reference it in CamelCase?

Comment: Also, I will be trying the other ways to do this which you posted as well. I appreciate all of the input. Wish I was allowed to mark both answers as correct.